# sorting unix type date in mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, date

Is there any way to retrieve SORTED resultset from mysql table where date is stored in unix way? I mean something like this "Select * from tableName order by DATE DESC", if its in Unix type it means it is stored as integer or bigint, so it doesnt really work that way I wrote here, any help?

Comment: I think sorting an integer or bigint works great. In fact numbers are pretty easy to sort. What do you believe the issue will be?

Comment: Following on from @mconlin, have you tried sorting by the actual value yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

```
SELECT ..
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(column)
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order the data by date instead of the unix int/bigint then you can convert the unix time to a date using [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
select *
from tableName
order by FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE) desc
```

Ordering by the unix value before the conversion should still work because it is an int value.